# Any way to find the deleted workflow rules?

Tags: apex, workflow, workflowrule

I was helping my company to mass update CASE records in one of our sandboxes. In order to expedite the process, I deactived all its workflow rules (object Case) before the update. After the update is done, now I am trying to activate the rules again, surprisingly, all the rules are gone. I am pretty sure that I only deactived the rules (not DELETE) before I did the mass update, but why the rules are disappeared?

This is only happened to the object Case, for all other objects, the deactivated rules are still there. Did I do something wrong to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Workflow Rules have List Views. If you're certain you haven't deleted them, it might be you're using the wrong List View. You can also create a new List View if you want to customize the list.

[image: Workflow List Views]

Comment: And i was about to suggest query "WorkflowRule" object using tooling api